# Como atualizar o framework .Net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, atualização

Como atualizar o framework do meu projeto?

Comment: No site oficial do framework, você encontra a versão mais recente:
http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=30653 Aqui você encontra um bom tutorial para a atualização:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2012/10/19/upgrading-target-framework-from-4-0-to-4-5-for-asp-net-mvc-applications.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto > <kbd>Properties</kbd>:

[image: Properties]

Na opção *Target framework*, selecione a opção correspondente ao novo Framework que você irá usar:

[image: Target Framework]

Caso a opção desejada não esteja entre as exibidas, clique em *Install other frameworks...* e siga os passos de instalação das telas que forem exibidas. Para cada *Framework* normalmente é uma tela peculiar.