# Utilizando [ForeignKey("")] - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Meu dominio está de seguinte forma

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Dominio
{
    public class Bolsa_AlunoProva
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Nota { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataFinal { get; set; }

        public virtual Bolsa_Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Bolsa_ProvaID")]
        public virtual Bolsa_Prova Prova { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Porém, não consigo utilizar o `[ForeignKey("Bolsa_ProvaID")]` pois ele aponta falta de referências. Porém, a referencia necessária não é apenas `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` ?

@edit

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode colocar exatamente o erro que está aparecendo pra você na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa anotação só existe para o .NET Framework 4.5 em diante. Considere mudar sua aplicação para o Framework 4.5.

[Ensino isso nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33202/2999).

Mais: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

O using correto é o: `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Comment: Infelizmente o .Schema não é reconhecido na minha aplicação. Editei minha pergunta e adicionei um print.